# Installing SQL Server Integration Services on Server Core

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, windows-server

I have `Windows Server 2008 R2 Core` on virtual machine and want to install SQL Server Integration Services. On the `D:/` drive `SQL Server 2014 Enterprise` `.iso` is mount.

I am reading a book where it is said that:

> You can use the Setup.exe command-line utility to add SSIS to an
>   existing installation on both traditional and Server Core deployments
>   of SQL Server 2012. For example, to add the SSIS feature to the
>   default MSSQLSERVER instance, run the following command:
>
> ```
> Setup.exe /qs /Action=Install /Features=IS /InstanceName=MSSQLServer
> /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
> ```

but I am getting the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is from the **Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Database** book. Make sure you have the initial SQL Server engine installed. Your syntax is exactly right though. I went through it again 10 minutes ago.

Also your ISO is from SQL Server 2014. Try mounting the SQL Server 2012 version.

Answer (score 1):

very Easy for you:

enter in powershell mode

and write this code:

```
./setup /UIMODE=EnableUIOnServerCore /ACTION=INSTALL
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server Setup Control /QS: Optional
>   Specifies that Setup runs and shows progress through the UI, but does not accept any input or show any error messages.

`/QS` **is Upper case**

You should use Upper case for all parameters since they are all Upper cases: [Install SQL Server 2014 from the Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.120).aspx)

> /QS Specifies that Setup runs and shows progress through the UI, but does not accept any input or show any error messages.

I think you should use /Q + /INDICATEPROGRESS:

```
Setup.exe /Q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=IS /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLServer /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS
```

All the output will be shown on the command line.

Comment: I get the same error message this time saying `[\QS]` is unknown.

Comment: did you put a backslash ? `\QS` or `/QS` ?

Comment: Still  not working and still getting the same error but about `/Q`

Comment: Let me check again later next week. I don't have a core server with me right now.